# How to make Onclick="window.location... open in new window?

Tags: javascript, reddit

I am using this Reddin button code and when i try to Submin post its open in the same window and go out from my site.. 
I want the code to open same as facebook share button works.. 
when i click it i want it wo open in new window size somthing like 500*500
or in new tab if its not possible 
this is the code i am using:

```
<a href="//www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.location = '//www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location); return false"> <img src="//www.redditstatic.com/spreddit10.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /> </a>
```

This is open in the same window, is it possible to make this code open in new tab or new window like popup?
i know there is a lot questions about this and i the answers there but its not working here with this code. i tried to replace the onclick="window.location to open window but with _blunk as they said.. but is just open new window + move the main site to the link itself..
so please help me
Thanks a lot! 
And sorry about my English :)

Comment: `window.open(link);`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="//www.reddit.com/submit" onclick="window.open('http://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location),'_blank')"> <img src="//www.redditstatic.com/spreddit10.gif" alt="submit to reddit" border="0" /> </a>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but its just make different problem.. when i click the button its transfer my site + opne new window..

Comment: please make href attribute to null